# How to define entity identity

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is there a way to define which attributes of an entity should define its objects' `NSManagedObjectID`?

Rather than having to build extra dictionaries and loops to compare them by property values, I'd like to be able to just use `-[NSManagedObjects isEqual:]` directly, and the `NSSet` functionality that would also allow.

Put another way: if an entity has an attribute that would logically be its primary key, how to tell CoreData to use it as such for object equality tests?

Comment: Ideally I don't want to have to subclass `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't**. And subclassing wouldn't help anyway.

Core Data doesn't care if you create duplicate records. As far as it's concerned, two managed objects are equal if they represent the same underlying instance in the persistent store. It has no other concept of "equal" between managed objects.

Subclassing doesn't help because, as the docs for `NSManagedObject` explain:

> `NSManagedObject` itself customizes many features of `NSObject` so that managed objects can be properly integrated into the Core Data infrastructure. Core Data relies on `NSManagedObject`’s implementation of the following methods, which you therefore absolutely must not override: [...] `isEqual:`,

You can create your own methods for comparing managed objects any way you like, but any behavior that relies on `isEqual:` is going to get Core Data's standard behavior.